# Pipe or log APT, keeping Notes

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

I am making a script that installs a dynamic list of packages and I need to know if a package is 'redirected' to another packages such as rpm-dbg -> librpm-dbg. The way I was going to do that was as follows:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends --no-remove -y --simulate install $file >ptmp 2>&1
if [[ `cat ptmp` == *Note,\ selecting ]]
then
    file=`cat ptmp|grep Note,|awk -F\' '{ print $2; }'`
fi
```

However I found out that by using '>' to dump the output into a file it acts like it had -q passed to it. I also tried '&>' and '|cat>' with the same results. So what I am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer [elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207470&p=12938965#post12938965). Here is the solution:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends --no-remove -y --simulate -q=0 install <PACKAGE>
```